# See which workflows affect a field in MS CRM

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015

The title says it all. Is there any way to see which processes / workflows touch a certain field of an entity in MS CRM?

Reason I am asking is because a lot of times I am looking at which process has touched the field, or can touch the field. Instead of going through all of them separately it would be great if this can be done the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the solution -> Entity -> Field, and click on Show Dependencies, it should tell you which views, forms, and workflows / processes are using it.

However, It's not going to tell you where is that field used in custom code (plugins, codeactivities) and that's one of the good reasons of having automated unit testing / CI process in place.

Hope this helps.